# Что в Java является константой, а что - нет?

Tags: java, переменные, интерфейс, константа

До недавнего времени я был почти на 100% убеждён в том, что прекрасно понимаю сущность констант в языке программирования Java. Так было, пока я не наткнулся на один из примеров, который был представлен в JLS (Java Language Specification). Он немного поверг меня в ступор, и я не могу разобраться с этим вопросом вплоть до текущего момента.

Наверное, я не сильно ошибусь, если скажу, что типичных констант в языке программирования Java нет вообще (во всяком случае, если смотреть с колокольни какого-нибудь С++). Даже ключевое слово `const`, которое зарезервировано с незапамятных времён, но до сих пор не используется, как бы ненавязчиво намекает нам об этом (не уверен, но вроде бы это было сделано для того, чтобы сохранить обратную совместимость с С++ в том случае, если константы всё-таки будут введены в язык).

В качестве некоторого общепринятого суррогата используется связка модификаторов `static final` в процессе декларирования переменной. Если я правильно понимаю, то именно такие переменные и считаются константами с точки зрения программистского сообщества ЯП Java. В то же время, если заглянуть на просторах JLS в параграф, который посвящён инициализации классов и интерфейсов, мы можем наткнуться на один интересный момент. Небольшая выдержка оттуда:

> Example 12.4.1-3. Interface Initialization Does Not Initialize Superinterfaces

```
interface I {
    int i = 1, ii = Test.out("ii", 2);
}
interface J extends I {
    int j = Test.out("j", 3), jj = Test.out("jj", 4);
}
interface K extends J {
    int k = Test.out("k", 5);
}
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(J.i);
        System.out.println(K.j);
    }
    static int out(String s, int i) {
        System.out.println(s + "=" + i);
        return i;
    }
}
```

> This program produces the output:
>
> 1
>   j=3
>   jj=4
>   3
>
> The reference to J.i is to a field that is a constant
>   variable (§4.12.4); therefore, it does not cause I to be initialized
>   (§13.4.9).
>
> The reference to K.j is a reference to a field actually declared in
>   interface J that is not a constant variable; this causes
>   initialization of the fields of interface J, but not those of its
>   superinterface I, nor those of interface K.
>
> Despite the fact that the name K is used to refer to field j of
>   interface J, interface K is not initialized.

И вот этот момент мне совершенно непонятен! В интерфейсах все поля неявным образом помечаются как `public static final` (другими они и не могут быть), что мы и видим в приведённом примере. Все поля имеют совершенно одинаковый набор модификаторов, но при этом, поле `J.i` называют константной переменной, а `K.j` константой уже не является, если верить примеру, который приведён в JLS.

Что же такое константа с точки зрения JLS? Неужели это не абсолютно все статические финализированные поля? Правильно ли я понял, что при присваивании значения через его возврат функцией, мы уже не можем считать поле константой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[С точки зрения JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

> A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type String that is initialized with a constant expression

То есть константа - это `final` переменная (причем речь не только о `static` и не только о полях) примитивного типа или типа `String`, которая проинициализирована [константным выражением](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

Вызов метода константным выражением не является, поэтому `K.j` - это не константа